# Service MySQl cant start

Tags: mysql, laragon

"I was using phpMyAdmin with Laragon without any issues, then after a restart, I am getting this error. What configuration changes should I make, please?"

[image]
[image]

I tried to do the update, but I couldn't retrieve the data from the backup.